# need help on luhns algorithm using 'C' for CS50

Tags: c, cs50, luhn

The issue im having with my code is the following:

1. line 15, not recognising the brackets as related despite that it is
2. as well as not recognising the first semi colon in (x/10; x<10, ++count);
3. not recognising the divide symbol and greater than symbol (x/10; x<10, ++count);
4. line 22, count = 15 || count = 16); apparently both of these numbers are not assignable.

```
// check credit number if valid
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    long x;
    int count;
    count = 0;
    printf("Please enter your credit card number: \n");
    scanf("%ld", &x);
    while (x >= 9)
        {
        (x/10; x>10, ++count);
        }
    printf("length of card number: ld, count");
    if (count != 13 || count != 15 || count != 16)
        {
        printf("is invalid, \n");
        }
    if (count = 13 || count = 15 || count = 16); 
        {
        printf("is valid, \n");
        }
}
```

Comment: `x/10` and `x>10` are evaluated, but have no effect. `x` keeps the same value.

Comment: `(count != 13 || count != 15 || count != 16)` will always be true. You need `&&` instead of `||`.

Answer (score 2):

`(x/10; x>10, ++count);` looks like you are attempting to write the expressions of a `for` loop. You cannot just write these as an isolated statement. A `for` statement has the form:

> `for (` *clause-1* `;` *expression-2* `;` *expression-3* `)` *statement*

*clause-1* may be either a declaration or an expression. It is evaluated at the start of the loop.

The body of the loop, in *statement*, which may be a compound statement (`{` … `}`), is executed as long as *expression-2* evaluates to true just before the *statement* begins. After each execution of *statement*, *expression-3* is evaluated.

Note that semicolons are used for both separators; there is no comma.

If you intended these conditions to be merged with the `while` you have before them, you need to restructure the entire thing into a `for` loop or other proper C structure.

In the first `if` statement, `count != 13 || count != 15 || count != 16` is wrong. `count` is **always** either not equal to 13 **or** not equal to 15, because it can never be equal to both. Think again about what condition you want to test.

In the second `if` statement, the operator for **comparing** values is `==`. In contrast, `=` is the operator for **assigning** a value.

Comment: you are awesome, thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure what you're trying to do here, but those parentheses are wrong; are you maybe confusing them with `for` statement syntax?
2. Same as #1.
3. Same as #1.
4. `=` is the assignment operator. You want `==`.

Comment: nice one man. thank you